# How to store a date in a cookie?

Tags: php

I have a javascript library that read date in this form:

```
12/31/2020 5:00 AM
```

So I need to save a date in that form in a cookie.
I write this code:

```
setcookie("invexpire", time()+3600*24, time()+3600*24*365);
echo $_COOKIE['invexpire'];
```

but it display something like this:

```
1340702563
```

So, How can I store a date in that form in a cookie ?

Answer (score 1):

*Format* the timestamp in that format:

```
date('m/d/Y g:i A', time()+3600*24)
```

http://php.net/date

Answer (score 1):

use [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format your timestamp:

```
$timestamp = time()+3600*24;
setcookie("invexpire", date('m/d/Y g:i A', $timestamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

The date you are displaying is a UNIX TimeStamp. It can be further formatted into any date string.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s A', time()+3600*24); For 2012-06-26 03:16:29 PM
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()+3600*24); For 2012-06-26 15:16:29
```