# How to get a date in this form?

Tags: javascript

I need to get a date in this form:

```
"12/31/2020 5:00 AM"
```

I wrote this code:

```
var ExpireI = new Date ();
ExpireI.setTime(ExpireI.getTime() + (24 * 3600 * 1000));
alert(ExpireI.toGMTString());
```

but it display something like this:

```
Tue, 26 Jun 2012 10:26:35 GMT
```

so, how can I get a date in that form ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store a date in a cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186859/how-to-store-a-date-in-a-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

Instead of doing this way:

```
getDate()     // Returns the date
getMonth()    // Returns the month
getFullYear() // Returns the year
```

And for your case, you can use this way:

```
alert(ExpireI.getFullYear() + "-" + ExpireI.getMonth() + "-" + ExpireI.getDate());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EHQrf/20/) here... :)

Comment: In case, `format()` is not working, you can use `toString()` function.

Comment: Updated answer. Check `alert(ExpireI.getFullYear() + "-" + ExpireI.getMonth() + "-" + ExpireI.getDate());` and let me know if it doesn't work... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EHQrf/20/) updated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
var d = new Date ();
var date = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;  // because january is 0 in javascript
var year = d.getFullYear();
var hour = d.getHours();
var min = d.getMinutes();
var m;
if(hour > 12 ){
  hour-=12;  
  m = 'PM';
}
else{
 m = 'AM';
}

console.log(month + '/' + date + '/' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ' ' + m);
```